# How to raise errors in tests in a shell script to CircleCI

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I have a Python syntax check shell script running in CircleCI. The shell scripts scans some folders and check the syntax of Python files (*.py). But somehow when there is an error, CircleCI still thinks that it is successful.

Here is an example of the syntax failures:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
sh ../ci/test-python-syntax.sh

  File "./fooboo.py", line 11
    import
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Still the shell script is marked successful. How can I make this script failed when this type of errors happens?

Comment: Can you please share the shell script itself, so we can see how it handles errors, and what kind of exit codes it returns?

You may need to set -o pipefail (See here  https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/using-shell-scripts/) to fail if bash script encounters ANY errors, rather than returning default last exit code in pipeline.

Comment: I would guess that the return code of the inner script is non-zero, and the outer script returns zero. You need to use `exit` with the return code of the inner script.